# Getting an index error in a python fibonacci program

Tags: python, list, fibonacci

I just started "Algorithmic toolbox" on Coursera, and was writing their version of the Fibonacci program in python 2.7

```
def fibonacci(n):
    F = []
    F[0] = 0
    F[1] = 1

    for i in range(0,n):
        F[i] = F[i-1] + F[i-2]

    return F[n]

fibonacci(3)
```

But, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fibonacci.py", line 11, in <module>
    fibonacci(3)
  File "fibonacci.py", line 3, in fibonacci
    F[0] = 0


IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: When you do `F= []`, you have effectively fixed the size of the array to be 0. If you want to _add_ elements to the array afterwards, you have to do `F.append(<element>)`.

Comment: Its size isn't fixed at 0 - it just doesn't have elements at the given indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create *new* elements in a Python list by assigning to non-existing indices. Your list is empty, so indices `0` and `1` *don't exist*.

Use `list.append()` instead:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    F = [0, 1]  # a list with two initial elements

    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        F.append(F[i-1] + F[i-2])  # add new value to the list

    return F[n]
```

Note that the loop starts at *`2`*, not `0`, because you already have the values for `0` and `1`. The stop argument to `range()` is *not included* so if you want to find the `n`th fibonacci number, you need to run the range up to `n + 1`.

Now the code works:

```
>>> def fibonacci(n):
...     F = [0, 1]
...     for i in range(2, n + 1):
...         F.append(F[i-1] + F[i-2])
...     return F[n]
...
>>> fibonacci(10)
55
```

Note that you don't really need to store all values in a list; you only need to track the *last 2*. You could use just two variables and swap these around for each iteration; one stores the

```
def fibonacci(n):
    prev, curr = 0, 1  # two variables, one set to 0, the other to 1
    for _ in range(n - 1):  # run n - 2 times
        prev, curr = curr, prev + curr
    return curr
```

Note that this doesn't do any boundary tests on `n`, so for `n = 0` the result is going to be incorrect (1 is returned rather than 0). This is easily remedied with a `if n < 1: return 0` line at the top.

Comment: Your loop should run up to `n` though `for i in range(2, n + 1): ...` and you might want to fix the `apppend` typo. Could't do it myself since it's less than 6 characters :)

Comment: @OChem1: yes, because in a previous revision the `range()` didn't run up until `n`. Already fixed.

Comment: Ahh sorry. Hadn't hit refresh. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems with your code:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    F = [] #3
    F[0] = 0
    F[1] = 1

    for i in range(0,n):
        F[i] = F[i-1] + F[i-2] #1

    return F[n] #2
```

1. First iteration this will be `F[0] = F[-1] + F[-2]`, which is well defined in Python but not what you want. You might want to review Python's indexing scheme.
2. `F[n]` refers to the n+1th element, since Python is 0 indexed. Range is [lower, upper), so it doesn't actually have `i = n` on the final iteration.
3. As Martijn commented below, the third issue is that you can't simply index into an empty list. You have to either do successive appends, or allocate the entire list as `F = [0]*n`.

Comment: Even if I change it to  `for i in range(2,n): `  It still won't work. So my first iteration would be `F[0] = F[1] + F[0]`

Comment: @OChem1: that's because `F[n]` doesn't exist, as the last value the `range()` produces is `n - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when the program reaches `F[0]` it tries to evaluate what's in the 0th index of `F`. The trouble is that `F` is initially an empty list and thus has no 0th index. You want to append those elements using `F.append(0)` and `F.append(1)`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append values to the list, because its of size 0. Python lists do not autogrow when you add an item at the next index, you have to specify it, for example with the `append` function

```
F = []
F.append(0)
F.append(1)
# [0, 1]

# OR
F = [0, 1]
# [0, 1]
```

Comment: The OP is also using `F[i] = ...` assignment. For any n > 1 that's going to be a problem.

Answer (score -4):

you need to start your loop at 2 not 0.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    F = [0,1]
    if n<0:
        return None
    if n<2:
        return F[n]
    for i in range(2,n):
        F[i] = F[i-1] + F[i-2]
    return F[n]
fibonacci(3)
```

Comment: This doesn't address OP's problem. The error occurs at `F[0] = 0`